# Vue - passing v-model from child to parent in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm building a form builder in Vue which allows users to add/remove various types of input. My method so far is to have a template component for each input type, then when a user selects that input type I push it into an array on the parent component to loop over and display.

However, I also need to pass the value of the input up to the parent (and store it in the `input type="hidden"` element), so I'm emitting an event in the child component and catching it in the parent. My problem is that the value of `labelText` gets updated identically for every `input type="hidden"` at once when I type, rather than individually. I can't work out what I'm missing?

**Text input template**

```
<template>
  <div id="TextInput">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Question" class="form__input_label" @input="sendLabelUp($event.target.value)" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Test placeholder" />
    <slot name="removeField"></slot>
    <slot name="hiddenInputs"></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TextInput',
  methods: {
    sendLabelUp: function(val) {
      this.$emit('input', val);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Parent template** (just including the part I think is relevant)

```
<transition-group name="form__input_list" tag="div">
    <component :is="input.type" v-for="(input, index) in inputs" v-bind="input" :key="input" v-model="labelText" class="form__input">
        <div slot="removeField">
          <a class="btn btn--tertiary sml-push-top-half" @click="removeField(index)">Remove</a>
        </div>
        <div slot="hiddenInputs">
          <!-- Hidden inputs used to store question config -->
          <input type="hidden" :name="`pages[0]questions[${index}]type[${input.type}]label[${labelText}]`" />
        </div>
    </component>
</transition-group>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'InputGenerator',
  components: {
    TextInput,
    TextArea,
    NumberInput,
    LikertScale,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [],
      dropdownActive: false,
      labelText: '',
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there-  from an architecture perspective, would it not be easier to have the controls governing which inputs are shown on the parent component?

Comment: why not use `v-model="input"` instead of `v-model="labelText"` right now you v-model all child component to one same object='labelText'; and why you bind twice and bind to different object (actually v-model will do v-bind also)?

Comment: Hi @Sparky, apologies I missed that part from my code sample - in my parent component I do have the buttons which create inputs, e.g. `<a @click.prevent="addField('TextInput')">Add text field</a>`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi @Sphinx you're right that does sound like the issue, but would you be able to expand on how I'd solve it? If I use `v-model="input"` I get a console error: `You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias.`. Will I need to use `v-model` on a property of the input object, rather than the input alias itself?

Comment: Yes, so could you not have some element within the parent - say a containing div or a sibling element such as a checkbox or button - that would allow you to remove the child. It would avoid all the complicated business of sending a message from the child to parent. Of course one way of managing global state is to use Vuex, but I don’t know whether it’s worth doing that just for this use case.

Comment: I think you're right there's definitely an easier way of achieving what I'm after without needing to pass data up. Thanks for making me think about that :)